# Unable to decode byte slice back into struct

Tags: arrays, go, struct

I am trying to read a byte array and output it into a struct in Go. The [official example](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) is a good starting point, but this only decodes a single `float64`.  This [other snippet](https://play.golang.org/p/cbHX5Twyrw) shows that it definitely can be done with structs.

My [play](https://play.golang.org/p/cX6YgeBPGj), however, fails with `binary.Read: invalid type ...` .

I thought this was to do with the Read function accepting only fixed-length data to read into:

> binary.Read reads structured binary data from r into data. Data must
>   be a pointer to a fixed-size value or a slice of fixed-size values

This is why my `struct` definition contains only fixed-length data.

I can't see that I'm doing anything vastly different to the working examples, and the error code isn't much help beyond the length issue - any ideas?

Comment: You have problem with writing to buffer, buffer length is 0 - https://play.golang.org/p/Fyq-5TAHRa

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/P9hX3lk_FI - the write returns error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problems with you struct that it has unexported fields.

Here is the working code:

https://play.golang.org/p/LHTeF-_2lX

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "net"
)

type myEvent struct {
    IP_version int32
    Ipv6_src_addr [16]byte
}


func readFromByteArrayIntoStruct() {

    // create event
    ip := net.ParseIP("2001::face")
    var ipBytes [16]byte;
    copy(ipBytes[:], ip.To16())
    event := myEvent {
        IP_version: 4, 
        Ipv6_src_addr: ipBytes,
    }

    // convert to bytes
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if err := binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, event); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Write failed:", err)
        return
    }
    eventBytes := buf.Bytes()
    fmt.Println(buf.Len(), eventBytes)

    // read back the bytes into a new event
    reader := bytes.NewReader(eventBytes)
    var decodedEvent myEvent 

    if err := binary.Read(reader, binary.BigEndian, &decodedEvent); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Read failed:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("decodedEvent: %+v", decodedEvent)
    }
}

func main() {
    readFromByteArrayIntoStruct()
}
```

Comment: Aha.. thank you.  That's easy to miss especially when using a struct that is not exported.

Comment: I am surprised that `Read()` doesn't also error due to the struct not being exported.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the struct is exported because it doesn't need to reference the type, as it already has an instance of the type. It does need to reference the members though, so they must be exported.